# Intersect Area service with points

Tags: geocoding, area, html, intersect

I'm making a map viewer for my university final work but I have no clue of coding. I've been following the ESRI Dashboard tutorials and I've arrived to the code as I have it now.

I have two buttons, one is for reseting the areas "Reestablecer" and the other one is supposed to calculate the intersection of the service area and the points and highlight the points intersected (then I'll have to extract the data from those intersected points), but its not working, I don't know why. How can I fix this?

The code is here, programmed in HTML and CodeOpen:

```
    <html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Visor del TFG de Francisco</title>
  <style>
    html, body, #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #controls {
            width: 250px;
            padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
          }
          .esri-button {
            margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
          }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.26/esri/themes/light/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.26"></script>
  <script>
    require([
      "esri/config",
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/rest/networkService",
      "esri/rest/serviceArea",
      "esri/rest/support/ServiceAreaParameters",
      "esri/rest/support/FeatureSet",
      "esri/Graphic",
      "esri/widgets/ScaleBar",
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
      "esri/widgets/Sketch",
      "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
      "esri/geometry/geometryEngine"
    ], function (
      esriConfig,
      Map,
      MapView,
      networkService,
      serviceArea,
      ServiceAreaParameters,
      FeatureSet,
      Graphic,
      ScaleBar,
      FeatureLayer,
      Sketch, 
      GraphicsLayer,
      geometryEngine
    ) {
      esriConfig.apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY"; // write here your API key that can be obtained for free in the ESRI dashboard
      const url = "https://route-api.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/ServiceAreas/NAServer/ServiceArea_World";
      let travelMode = null;
      
      // Definición del mapa base a cargar
      const map = new Map({
        basemap: "arcgis-navigation"
      });
      
      // Creación del widget de sketch
      const graphicsLayerSketch = new GraphicsLayer();
      
      // Apartado de carga de la propia vista inicial del mapa.
      const view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map,
        center: [-0.37739, 39.4697],
        zoom: 12,
        constraints: {
          snapToZoom: false
        }
      });
      
      // Apartado de carga de los puntos de equipamientos
      const trailheadsLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: "https://services.arcgis.com/mtxQAl9zwVlYIRpr/arcgis/rest/services/equipamientos/FeatureServer/0"
      });
      
      
      
      // Apartado para añadir los equipamientos, al mismo tiempo que otros widgets
      map.add(trailheadsLayer);
      view.ui.add(new ScaleBar({ view, unit: "metric", style: "ruler" }), "bottom-right");
      map.add(graphicsLayerSketch);
      view.ui.add(document.getElementById("controls"), "top-right");
      document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click",resetGraphics);
      
      
      //Creación de las áreas de servicio
      view.when(() => {
        createServiceAreas(view.center);
      });
      view.on("click", (event) => {
        createServiceAreas(event.mapPoint);
      });
      function createServiceAreas(point) {
        // Remove any existing graphics
        view.graphics.removeAll();
        const locationGraphic = createGraphic(point);
        findServiceArea(locationGraphic);
      }
      // Aquí se crea un polígono gráfico en el punto donde se selecciona
      function createGraphic(geometry) {
        // Se definen las características del punto
        const graphic = new Graphic({
          geometry,
          symbol: {
            type: "simple-marker",
            color: "white",
            size: 8
          }
        });
        view.graphics.add(graphic);
        return graphic;
      }

      async function findServiceArea(locationFeature) {
        if (!travelMode) {
          const networkDescription = await networkService.fetchServiceDescription(url);
          travelMode = networkDescription.supportedTravelModes.find(
            (travelMode) => travelMode.name === "Walking Distance"
          );
        }

        const serviceAreaParameters = new ServiceAreaParameters({
          facilities: new FeatureSet({
            features: [locationFeature]
          }),
          defaultBreaks: [1.25], // km
          travelMode,
          travelDirection: "to-facility",
          outSpatialReference: view.spatialReference,
          trimOuterPolygon: true
        });
        const resultsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
        const { serviceAreaPolygons } = await serviceArea.solve(url, serviceAreaParameters);
        showServiceAreas(serviceAreaPolygons);
      }

      function showServiceAreas(serviceAreaPolygons) {
        const graphics = serviceAreaPolygons.features.map((g)=>{
          g.symbol = {
            type: "simple-fill",
            color: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25)"
          }
          return g
        })
        view.graphics.addMany(graphics, 0);
      }
      
      const intersectGeom = geometryEngine.intersect(view.graphics, view.trailheadsLayer);
      const intersectionGraphic = new Graphic({
        geomtry: intersectGeom,
        symbol: {
          type: "simple-fill",
          style: "cross",
          color: "green",
          outline: {
            color: "green"
          }
        }
      });
      resultsLayer.add(intersectionGraphic)
      document.getElementById("intersect").addEventListener("click",findIntersect);
      function resetGraphics() {
        view.graphics.removeAll()
        return;
      }
      
     
      
      
      
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  <div id="controls" class="esri-widget">
      <button id="intersect" class="esri-button">Intersecar</button>
      <button id="reset" class="esri-button esri-button--secondary">Reestablecer</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Ad a new user, please take the [Tour]. "It is not working" is a really vague problem statement, which doesn't give much of a chance for someone to help you. Please [Edit] the Question to state what it isn't doing, and what it's doing instead, Error console output might be needed as well.